# how to deployment dart app to javascript in the server?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart2js

to do with the files in the `build/web` folder in my dart app to deployed a in the server as Javascript?

I want to deployd my app but as javascript. But i don't know the correct procedure.

I have configured my project and I called in my localhost

> build pub

has generated the folder

```
build / web
```

What is the next step to run my dart app as Javascript on the server?

or I should be `call build` pub on the server?

Comment: Do you want dart code to be run on server side? Or just get compiled js files from server to browser and run on browser?

Comment: get compiled js files from server to browser and run on browser. currently not find the file. (404 test.dart.js )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should grab all files inside this `build / web` folder and put them into static-served folder of your server (for Apache it is often `htdocs` folder).

Than you should be able to open html file of your app and get app working.

Comment: thanks Valentyn, I thought it will be compiled on the server. Then each time i modify the application I have to compile everything and only upload that folder? no way to push the code and compile on the server?

Comment: @DanielCastillo it is preferred way to compile and push compiled version. Of Course if you server have Dart installed you can or upload changes each time, and do `pub build` or you can serve directly by `pub serve` - in this case you don't need to recompile - you keep it running and it will pick up changes automatically.